# Свой Курсор

Tags: java, swing

Добрый день. Каким образом в java можно поменять стандратную стрелочку курсора на свою собственную картинку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();  
Image image = toolkit.getImage("pencil.gif");  
Cursor cursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(image, hotSpot, "Pencil");  
setCursor(cursor);  
//via http://www.codebeach.com/2008/02/using-custom-cursors-in-java.html
```